# Return multiple integers from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, integer, return, preg-match

I am trying to return the numbers from a string as separate integers. The string has the following markup:

```
$string = "20 x 20 cm";
```

The number 20 could be a larger number as well. e.g. 70 x 93 cm or 120 x 230 cm, so it isn't always equal to each other.

I've read about Preg_Match, but couldn't figure it out. So now I'm here asking for your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the pattern that you tried...

Comment: if you know that it is always going to be a multiplication, you could use explode() on the "x" and the "cm"

Comment: If the spaces between the 'x' are constant, you can explode the string (space as delimiter) and use the keys [0] and [2]

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/axg-y1j - as suggested above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$string = '20 x 20 cm';
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
$arr = array($arr[0], $arr[2]);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I didn't think of using the explode function.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

```
$string = "20 x 20 cm";
$results = array();
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $results);
print_r($results[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex master, but I like to work with named subpatterns:

```
$string = "20 x 20 cm";
preg_match('/(?P<int1>\d+) x (?P<int2>\d+)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches['int1'].', '.$matches['int2'];
```

Another option would be `strtok`:

```
$int1 = strtok($string, ' x ');
$int2 = strtok(' x ');
echo $int1.', '.$int2;
```

Or use `sscanf`:

```
list($int1, $int2) = sscanf($string, "%d x %d cm");
echo $int1.', '.$int2;
```